# Set Values for datetime Index Slices

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I have a datetime indexed pandas DataFrame and I wish to replace different datetime ranges of values depending on the column. My DataFrame that stores the values looks as follows,

```
df1

Out[1]:
                       IL15 IL09 IL06
2016-06-23 00:00:00    1    1    1
2016-06-23 00:01:00    1    1    1
2016-06-23 00:02:00    1    1    1
2016-06-23 00:03:00    1    1    1
2016-06-23 00:04:00    1    1    1
2016-06-23 00:05:00    1    1    1
...
```

The date ranges, column headers and new values are stored in DataFrame `df2` show here,

```
df2

Out[2]:
    Start                   End                    Column_Head  New_Value
0   2016-06-23 04:35:00     2016-06-23 04:50:00    IL15          0
1   2016-06-23 02:55:00     2016-06-23 05:15:00    IL09          3
3   2016-06-23 05:15:00     2016-06-23 06:00:00    IL06          5
...
```

Currently, I am using a `for` loop over the `df2` index and then slicing `df1` as follows,

```
for i in df2.index:
    df1.loc[df2.Start[i]:df2.End[i], (df2.IndirectCode[i])] = df2.New_Value[i]
```

I can't help but think that there will be a nicer way within Pandas to do this.

The output would look something like this - though not necessarily correct to the section of data shown.

```
df1

Out[1]:
                       IL15 IL09 IL06
2016-06-23 00:00:00    0    1    1
2016-06-23 00:01:00    0    1    1
2016-06-23 00:02:00    1    1    1
2016-06-23 00:03:00    1    1    5
2016-06-23 00:04:00    1    3    5
2016-06-23 00:05:00    1    3    5
...
```

What is the best way in which to perform this type of slice replacement?

Comment: I did consider putting this on Code Review but it seems a little short for that. Is this the right place for this type of question?